# Website is not opening

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup

I am working on http://rojudeal.in/ website. Now my website is not opening. it shows following.[image]

Comment: same Error for me please contact Your hosting provider

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to contact your hosting provider as it seems like your server is either offline or blocking connections

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your DNS entry okay? (Is the IP address in this dig report correct?)

```
➜  ~ dig rojudeal.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> rojudeal.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52056
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;rojudeal.com.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
rojudeal.com.           533     IN      A       166.62.30.158

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 10.50.50.251#53(10.50.50.251)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 26 16:08:26 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46
```

Edit: Doing a reverse DNS lookup gives me an other result than your domainname:

```
➜  ~ dig -x 166.62.30.158

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -x 166.62.30.158
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59006
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;158.30.62.166.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
158.30.62.166.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN     PTR     ip-166-62-30-158.ip.secureserver.net.

;; Query time: 99 msec
;; SERVER: 10.50.50.251

#53(10.50.50.251)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 26 16:10:53 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 94
```